# Basic mathematical form: projecting 3D parabola onto 2D plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently working on a project to track tennis balls using video footage and I could really use some help!

I detect the ball in each frame and end up with x-y coordinates over time. Here's a sample image:

[image: sample trajectories]

Please ignore the overlaid motion of the player on the right; what's important is the track of the ball shown in green and sometimes circled in purple.

Here's the court the ball is moving on:

[image: court]

What I would like to ask your help with is the correct functional form I should use to fit my detected x-y coordinates. I'm expecting it to be close to a parabola in its own plane but obviously there is some projection going on. I tried to derive something myself but unfortunately my linear algebra is pretty rusty! A fourth-order poly fits the data well, but I'd rather have the *correct* form if possible.

Can you help me out and let me know what rough functional form to expect so I can fit the data in a more intelligent way? Is it a polynomial multiplied by some trigonometric function?

Thank you and all the best!

Comment: The projection onto 2D of a 3D parabola written in Bernstein-Bezier basis is a conic written in rational Bernstein-Bezier basis with one parameter in the standard form. The parameter control what kind of conic section you have. For an intro look at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve) and then look at Farin's books for more.